# Create a flat file using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis-2012

Hi I am trying to create a flat file (text file) from SQL Server Database View,
I have a date time column in dd/mm/yyyy format but I want this column to be converted as 'ddmmccyy' format in flat file. e.g. (25/07/2016 as 25072016). Secondly in text file I has to leave certain character blank space after each column    i.e. Starting byte:1    Ending byte:19
e.g ID column is having value '5' but in text file I have to add 18 blank space after this value and my next column should begin on starting byte 20. I have around 50 plus columns with different specification. If some one can help me how to achieve this as I am very new to SSIS I don't know how to achieve this using Data Conversion or Derived Columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are using sql-server, the convert function should take care of your date format problem.

Comment: For the fixed width output, just choose 'ragged right' (or fixed width) in your flat file connection manager, and set the column widths in 'advanced' section.

Answer (score 0):

To format the date, perhaps you can try the format function

```
Declare @Date date=getDate()
Select Format(@Date,'ddMMyyyy')
```

Returns 25072016

Unfortunately, I don't understand the second requirement

Comment: The second requirement is to produce a fixed length data file.

Comment: @DanBracuk  I understand that, just didn't follow the logic.